# Can I use the SP mailer to send email when not on a SP site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, csom, sharepoint-email

So I have access to a SP 2010 website but am developing another stand alone, non SP website on the same domain.

I haven't been given a mailer or an sql box so I've been using custom lists, an api and csom to load data from SP for this new site. I would love to also be able to use this SP box in the same way to send email.

I have tried several different ways but they all fail, making me wonder if I can even do this at all.

Anyone have any idea whether this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient to send email.
Sample code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com");
            mail.To.Add("u@urdomain.com");
            mail.Subject = filename;
            mail.Body = "Report";
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Some links for your reference:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/339835/Send-Email-using-SMTP-in-Csharp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx